# Migrating a repository to github with LFS object

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm migrating my repositories to github. So far so good except for one repo. In fact, when migrating this repo, I have following error:

```
error: File Project/Resources/AssessmentTool.zip is 134.92 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

So, I tried to use git lfs to tackle this as following:

```
git clone --mirror $oldURL
cd MY_CLONE
git remote add remoteName $newURL
git lfs push --all
```

But I have nothing on github.
So, what's the best procedure to migrate from a git server to github by also including LFS?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally, I found a solution. It appears my company github account does not allow LFS anyway. So, I found [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which helps me to avoid this big file. In all cases, I don't need this big file, so let's get rid of it.
Hence I first cloned my repository, then applied BFG and managed to push on github with following lines:

```
git clone --mirror myRepo.git
java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M .\myRepo.git\
cd myRepo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push -f --tags github refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

It works so hope this will help somebody else.